# Instagram login using Java Selenium Headless

Tags: java, selenium, instagram

When I use Selenium for Instagram, it works fine if I don't use Headless.
Adding the --headless option will result in a 404 page.

I'm wondering if I can crawl Instagram with the --headless option added to Java from now on.

If it works, I will figure out how to do it and share it.

Answer (score 1):

Headless browser it is detecting bot. Use `user-agent` to get rid of this.

```
options.addArguments("headless");
options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1280");
options.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("https://www.instagram.com/");
#print title to verify this
System.out.println("Tile :" + driver.getTitle());
```

---

Update try with following options.

```
options.addArguments("disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");
options.addArguments("headless");
options.addArguments("window-size=1920,1280");
options.addArguments("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36");
options.addArguments("--remote-debugging-port=9222");
```

Comment: Thank you.
Works on Windows, but not Centos7.

Comment: @shkim : Can you try with updated chrome option to check whether it works with Centos.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
I solved it through a chrome upgrade.
Thank you.